# C++ / Arduino serial.read to

Tags: c++, serial-port, arduino, usb, hid

I 'm trying to send the buffer of the USB HID input (which is always numeric) to the analogwrite function. So i need to convert it to a byte or an integer. Any idea how?

```
#include <HIDSerial.h>

HIDSerial serial;

unsigned char buffer[32];
ledPin = 10;

void setup() {
  serial.begin();
}

void loop() {
  if(serial.available()) {
    int size = serial.read(buffer);
    if (size!=0) {
      serial.write((const uint8_t*)buffer, size);
      // It will fail cause it needs a conversion from unsigned char to something else..
      analogWrite (ledPin,buffer)
    }
  }
  serial.poll();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i must have missed a detail here. What are you expecting and what is happening? Are you getting an "invalid conversion" error?

Comment: Yes and it seems logical. I can't convert a buffer to a byte. Maybe i should follow another approach

Comment: You need to create another array of ints that is the same length and transfer each value across then send each int. Have you used for loops?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a char to a uint8_t like this:

```
//assume these variables
char thisChar = '9';
uint8_t thisByte;

thisByte |= thisChar;

Serial.println(thisByte, BIN);
```

The output of this is: 00111001

This works because they are both a single byte variable. You are moving the bits over using a bitwise operation.

Comment: How does this relate to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do here.

`serial.read()` and `serial.write()` deal with a buffer of data up to 32 bytes long. You can't convert that to an integer in a meaningful way. Also note that `buffer` is a pointer to the memory where the data is located. It will be the same number every time, so it doesn't make sense to send that.

`analogWrite()` writes a PWM value from 0 to 255 to a pin. Is this really what you want to do?

Comment: Well, I need to send through the usb (using the HIDSerial library) a (byte) PWM value to the A0 pin. The hid-serial has the serial.read function. Any code help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

This is the full program:

```
#include <HIDSerial.h>

HIDSerial serial;

unsigned char buffer[2];

void setup() {
  serial.begin();
}

void loop() {
  if(serial.available()) {
    int size = serial.read(buffer);
    if (size!=0) {
      int bright = atoi((char *) buffer) ;
      analogWrite(0,bright);
      serial.println(bright);

    }
  }
  serial.poll();
}
```